# Reshape the mongodb aggregation result with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Sample Collection document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5fec3b978b34e8b047b7ae14"),
  "duration" : 20.0,
  "createdOn" : ISODate("2020-12-16T22:28:44.000Z"),
  "ClockInTime" : ISODate("2020-12-31T14:57:13.041Z"),
  "states" : "PROCESSED"
}
```

Currently i'm using the following query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                states: 'PROCESSED'
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    month: {
                        $month: "$createdOn"
                    },
                    year: {
                        $year: "$createdOn"
                    }
                },
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                },
                date: {
                    $first: "$createdOn"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                year: {
                    $year: "$date"
                },
                month: {
                    $month: "$date"
                },
                count: 1
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Which gives me the result in the following format.

```
[{
    "count" : 2.0,
    "year" : 2020,
    "month" : 11
}, {
    "count" : 5.0,
    "year" : 2020,
    "month" : 12
}, ...]
```

But i want the following format.

```
{
    "2020": {
        "11": 2,
        "12": 5
    }
}
```

Right now i'm able to get the above output by application level coding but i'm trying to get the same output from the mongodb query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the result you already have, add this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { result: [{ k: { $toString: "$month" }, v: "$count" }] } },
   { $set: { result: { $arrayToObject: "$result" } } },
   { $set: { result: [{ k: { $toString: "$year" }, v: "$result" }] } },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$result" } } }
])
```

Note, `date: { $first: "$createdOn" }` is not determined. Either use `date: { $min: "$createdOn" }` or insert `{$sort: {...}}` stage before you run `$group`. Well, if you get always just one document, then it does not matter of course. (but then you would not need `count: { $sum: 1 }` either)

**Update based on additional input**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { states: "PROCESSED" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: { $month: "$createdOn" },
        year: { $year: "$createdOn" }
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      date: { $first: "$createdOn" }
    }
  },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id.year", data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          in: {
            k: { $toString: "$$this._id.month" },
            v: "$$this.count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $set: { data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } },
  { $set: { data: [ { k: { $toString: "$_id" }, v: "$data" } ] } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } }
])
```

See [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1pujewwKhzr)

In older MonogDB version use `$addFields` which is an alias for `$set`

following code works for older mongodb versions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        states: "PROCESSED"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            month: {
                $dateToString: { format: "%m", date: "$createdOn" }
            },
            year: {
                $dateToString: { format: "%Y", date: "$createdOn" }
            }
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        date: {
            $first: "$createdOn"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.year",
        data: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        data: {
            $map: {
                input: "$data",
                in: {
                    k: "$$this._id.month",
                    v: "$$this.count"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        data: {
            $arrayToObject: "$data"
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        data: [{
            k: "$_id",
            v: "$data"
        }]
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
            $arrayToObject: "$data"
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: i got to know $set is new stage but i'm using mongodb 3.6 version.

Comment: i've tested this on latest version as well, It's not giving the output as expected. Following is the link for mongo playground of the same [Click](https://mongoplayground.net/p/juOCmMsIpR_)

Comment: please check the given link and i've updated my question .

Comment: `$toString` and `$convert` both doesn't work in version 3.6.

Comment: The it might be time to upgrade to version 4.4